# Why does Matthew 28:19 allege Jesus commanded men to "Worship with men's hands" (Acts 17:25) that makes two baptisms (Ephesians 4:5)?

Tags: new-testament

Ephesians 4:5 says "One LORD, one faith, one baptism,"

John 1:33 says "...the same is He which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost."

Psalm 18:30 says "As for God, His way is perfect:..."

Acts 10:44 shows Holy Spirit baptism as one baptism and Acts 10:47 shows water baptism is another baptism which makes Matthew 28:19 two baptisms although Ephesians 4:5 says "one baptism."

Why are there two baptisms in Scripture after the cross although Ephesians 4:5 says "one baptism" that also make men "Worship with men's hands" (Acts 17:25)?

SURE "This question is closed" because it doesn't adhere to catholic doctrine that leaves mankind "DEAD spirits" (Romans 5:12-14; I Corinthians 15:21-22) without His "POWER coming upon us" (Acts 1:8) when "He baptizes us with the Holy Ghost" (John 1:33; Acts 1:5) Who "QUICKENS" us (I Cor 15:45) "back to life" (Ephesians 2:1) from our "DEAD spirits"

"GOD is not the GOD of the DEAD" (Mark 12:27)!

Comment: Simply quoting more and more verses won't help anyone understand the contradiction you are seeing here.

Comment: This is not a Catholic site, most people here are not Catholics, and as far as I know none of the moderators are.

Comment: Scripture given is self explanatory!  Every Scripture given "overthrows" (Acts 5:39) catholic doctrine of TWO baptisms (Ephesians 4:5) after the cross which you and this site preach.  Therefore you uphold catholics and not the Word of God making you preach for catholics and are catholic.  Jesus said in Matthew 12:30 "Either you're with Me or against Me" and He said "one baptism" in Ephesians 4:5 but you and the majority of today's Christians preach catholic's TWO baptisms. "BLASPHEMY" (Matthew 12:30-32)!

Comment: You're doing NOTHING but  "denying the power of God" Jesus "...baptize you with the Holy Ghost" (John 1:33) "from such stay away" (II Timothy 3:5-7)!

Comment: Acts 10:44-47 shows that Christian baptism, unlike that of John (itself a version of Jewish ritual washings, prescribed in the Old Covenant), consists not merely of water alone, but of Spirit as well, echoing Christ's own words in John 3:5.

Answer (score 1):

The baptism of the Holy Spirit is the baptism that matters most.  The physical baptism in water is just a symbol, and it is a public commitment, or promise, to devote oneself to God.  But anyone, Christian or not, can be baptized; the act itself does not ensure one's salvation or even one's dedication to God.  Many have been baptized to secure a job, a salary, friends, popularity, or political advantage.  God reads the heart.  But the baptism of the Holy Spirit is clear evidence of one's acceptance with God.

The Bible likens God's people to a bride: God's bride.

> ". . . and as the bridegroom rejoiceth over the bride, so shall thy
> God rejoice over thee." (Isaiah 62:5)

Baptism, a ceremony by which one shows publicly a desire for lifelong commitment to God, is like a wedding ceremony.  The wedding ceremony itself means little if the marriage is not consummated.  The same is true with baptism: it is the Holy Spirit's abiding presence in the life that means most.

Jesus' conversation with Nicodemus helps us to understand the importance of the Holy Spirit as compared with water baptism.

> "Jesus answered, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born
> of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God.
> That which is born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of
> the Spirit is spirit. Marvel not that I said unto thee, Ye must be
> born again. The wind bloweth where it listeth, and thou hearest the
> sound thereof, but canst not tell whence it cometh, and whither it
> goeth: so is every one that is born of the Spirit."  (John 3:5-8)

To summarize, baptism can be likened to a wedding ceremony and a marriage: the wedding is brief, but marriage is lifelong.  Though they are two events, they can both be called "marriage"--one marriage.  In like manner, the two baptisms are really one: they both form part of one's commitment to and relationship with Christ.

Comment: "Two baptisms" defies Ephesians 4:5 that says "one baptism" and Acts 10:44; 47 witnesses they are two separate baptisms which is why Peter "REMEMBERED" in Acts 11:15-17.  No place in Scripture does it say "...they can both be called "marriage"---one marriage."  Today's Christians are undermining "God's perfection" (Psalms 18:30) when they "deny the power of God" (II Tim 3:5-7) "baptize them with the Holy Ghost" (John 1:33)!

Comment: @NorineJWilliams  For people to baptize with the Holy Spirit would be like choosing for themselves a prophet: Both are impossible, as only God can do it.  So it is with marriage: People choose to marry, but God takes credit for the couple's union, saying "What GOD has joined together, let no man put asunder." (Matthew 19:6)  Baptism by water may be a man-initiated ceremony, but for the convert's marriage to Christ to be complete, God's Holy Spirit must confirm it.  In the BIble, Jesus is said to go to a "marriage" (not a "wedding") in Cana. (See John 2:2).  I had this word usage in mind.

Comment: Did you read Scriptures given?  John 1:33 says "...the same is HE which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost"   So how does a man baptize a man with the Holy Ghost when Jesus has "all power" (Matt 28:18) Who "comes upon us" (Acts 1:8) after Holy Spirit baptism (Acts 1:5) the day "He chooses and ordains us" (John 15:16) and "receive power to become the sons of God" (John 1:12-13) as we "join to His Spirit" (I Corinthians 6:17)  Which is the only "marriage" that takes place?  We are "confirmed" with "signs following" (Mark 16:16-20) by His "power" (Acts 1:5;8) and "Spiritual gifts" (I Cor 12:7-10;13)

Answer (score 1):

Matthew 28:19

> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit,

Acts 17:25

> And he is **not** served by human hands, as if he needed anything. Rather, he himself gives everyone life and breath and everything else.

Why does Matthew 28:19 allege Jesus commanded men to “Worship with men's hands” (Acts 17:25)?

Matthew 28:19 does not make such an allegation.

Ephesians 4:5

> one Lord, one faith, **one baptism**;

Why does Matthew 28:19 allege Jesus commanded men to “Worship with men's hands” (Acts 17:25) that makes two baptisms (Ephesians 4:5)?

Again Matthew 28:19 does not make such an allegation.

Comment: Tell me how a man can baptize another man WITHOUT his hands?

Comment: Where did I assert that?

Comment: Therefore you are "Worshiping with men's hands" (Acts 17:25) water baptizing another man or vice versa.

Comment: Do you know what "assert" means? Can you quote what I wrote instead of putting words into my mouth?

Comment: @NorineJWilliams: With rare exceptions, the baptism of the Holy Spirit was also usually given by the laying down of the apostles' hands (e.g., Acts 8:18-19).

Comment: Tony there is no need of you denying "Jesus baptizes us with the Holy Ghost" (John 1:33) the "one baptism" (Ephesians 4:5) "perfectly" (Psalm 18:30) and Matthew 28:19 makes two baptisms.  Is "God the author of confusion" (I Corinthians 14:33)?

Comment: Why would you say that Lucian when Acts 2:39 says  "For the promise [Acts 1:4-5] is unto you, and to your children, and to all that are afar off, even as many as the Lord our God shall call?"

Comment: Today's Christians just don't know who have been taught by tradition a powerless water baptism when Holy Spirit baptism is HOW Jesus chooses and ordains us (John 15:16) to be Christians when we "witness" His POWER coming upon us after Holy Spirit baptism (Acts 1:5;8) which is "His resurrection" (Acts 1:22) to be members of the body of Christ (I Cor 12:11-13).  You just don't know!  I see all of these "bible scholars" trying to figure God out when "He reveals by His Spirit" (I Cor 2:10) after Holy Spirit baptism.   It's really sad that has created all these Christian denominations (I Cor 1:10).

Comment: This is a horrible site in that you must have "reputations" to comment.

Comment: People need help from God and I can't even answer questions nor comment under some question.  However what I do comment they "will put me out of the synagogue thinking they've done the Lord a service" not knowing it's from God.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood you. Sorry about that.